# Meta-data in achemso class: journal-appropriate affiliation format

Tags: achemso, affiliation

I am using achemso to prepare a manuscript for J. Phys. Chem. A.  Everything looks great except that the author/affiliation page has affiliation info both in the footnote and below the author list.  For the journal I am submitting to, no affiliation info goes in the footnote aside from a 'current address' or other footnote-type info.

Is there a way to only have the affiliation below the author list, have the affiliation symbols appear there, and have the affiliations each have their own line?  Currently they only appear in the footnote portion.

Borrowing from a previous question on achemso, here's my attempt at a basic example:

```
\documentclass[journal=jpcafh,manuscript=article,layout=traditional]{achemso}

\title{Title}

\author{Author 1}
\affiliation{lab 1}
\author{Author 2}
\affiliation{lab 2}
\email{author@lab}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

which gives this output:

[image: output]

As I am a LaTeX novice, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome, if this is really what the journal requires, we should inform @Josephwright.

Comment: Unless the _editorial office_ ask for changes, you really don't need to worry about this. The ACS re-typeset all accepted submissions, and so anything in 'manuscript form' is fine.

Comment: Thanks to both.  I was wondering about irritating reviewers with the wrong format, but if it's not an easy fix I won't sweat it.